# French Defense Exchange variation - Qh5?

Tags: french-defense, attack

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 exd5 4. Bd3 Bd6 5. Nc3 Ne7 6. Qh5
```

I played this as white, and my last move seem to bother my opponent a lot. So I'd like to know if 5. ... Ne7 is correct and if my early queen trip is justified. If this is the case, which attacking ideas does white have. I later put my bishop on g5 (which is pretty obvious), but after this I had the feeling that I could do more to keep the pressure.

Answer (score 4):

6.Qh5 is not so great because Black has 6...Nbc6, both attacking d4 and threatening ...Nb4 trading off White's important light-squared bishop (it can't move to e2 or something because of ...Nxc2+). White seems to be better off preemptively defending the d-pawn with a move like 6.Nf3 or 6.Nge2.

Comment: In the game white played the inferior `6. ... Be6`, but I met the later `Nbc6` with `Nb5!?`, which seems to work fine, and even managed to destroy the opponent's bishop pair.